# Process Builder - Revision (Deactivate and then Clone then Activate)

Tags: apex, workflow, visual-workflow, time-dependent-workflow, process-builder

Do I have to update the records again to trigger the process builder with the revised one, or does it automatically use the same Process with the updated version?

Answer (score 2):

It works how workflow or triggers operate .So moment you make change ,for data to reflect you will need to update records again .

Comment: And also you cannot deploy it!

Comment: @ManjunathNimbal Don't agree sir on this one .You can see process builder components under Flows .At backend a flow is generated from SFDC.

Comment: Yes I did that using change set. It gets deployed but when you run it in the target envi it errors out.

Comment: @ManjunathNimbal I tried this in my sandbox and i ran and was sucess .May be you can raise case with support and see .My process builder was very simple .